# How can I make Xui JS x$('') work with existing jquery code $('')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, xui

I suspect this is ridiculously simple, but I can't figure it out.

We have some simple code that we've written using jQuery, but I suspect it would work fine with xui, and since this is a mobile app saving the bits to download and the time to load all of the extra js in jQuery would be fantastic.

jQuery of courses uses $('') as the select, but xui uses x$('').  Is there a technique I can use, so that I can just swap the js libraries and have it work?

Is it as simple as: 
   var $ = x$;

at the start of my script?

Comment: rather than use $('#jQueryID') use jQuery('#jQueryId').  Also look at jQuery's noConflict() method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I'm sorry,but this doesn't answer the question.  I have code written for the jquery library that I want to port to the xui library without rewriting all of my selectors.

Comment: Why not get notepad++, you can do a regex-enhanced replace on all open documents making the computer rewrite all your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but after the initial variable declarations in xui.js, there's a declaration for x$ that looks like this:

```
window.x$ = window.xui = xui = function(q, context) {
    return new xui.fn.find(q, context);
};
```

You can probably change it to this so that you can seamlessly test it against your code written for jQuery, since other than in the comments, x$ is not referenced in the xui.js code itself:

```
window.$ = window.xui = xui = function(q, context) {
    return new xui.fn.find(q, context);
};
```

of if you wanted to leave x$ in there and just add $ as another selector, you can add it to the assignment like this:

```
window.x$ = window.$ = window.xui = xui = function(q, context) {
    return new xui.fn.find(q, context);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for following up on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think, just adding `window.$ = window.x$` or even only `$ = x$`, after loading xui should be sufficient.